# Google Find Device Remote Location Turning

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, remote-control, lost-phone, remote-access, location-services

Now, if I want to find my Lenovo Vibe P1 Turbo that runs on Marshmallow 6.0.1 and if the GPS is turned off on that phone

Can I remotely turn on the location on from my PC so I can find that phone ?

Comment: Maybe, and yes. // The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way. Best would be to move the second part to our sister site [Software Recommendations](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) (read behind the link for what's important there). For the remaining part: Have you any device-finder software installed?

Comment: @Izzy only Google Find Device

Comment: Then I'm afraid there's no chance. That one only works if location is already turned on. Others accept "commands" e.g. via SMS to toggle things. // I don't put this as answer as just because I don't know such thing exists doesn't mean there is, I might have missed it. But chances are rather small.

Comment: @Izzy IOS wins again...

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Especially with "again" ;)

Comment: @Izzy you can remotely turn on location for iPhones according to my searches

Comment: @Izzy also by again, this is one of the rare parts where iPhone is superior

Comment: Never got the chance to test that. But we're off-topic now. So hopefully someone comes up with the solution I've missed: good luck!